# One API or Two APIs one for internal use and the other for external use

Tags: c#, architecture, programming-practices, api, asp.net-core

I follow the `Layered architecture` Like this:

[image]

But with two differences:

- I use Blazor Assembly for UI Layer.
- I have `API layer`(REST) In between the `presentation layer` and the `service layer`.

---

My question is related to the Api design.

If I design the solution for `HR system` and for example It has three modules:

- Recruitment.
- Performance Management.
- Time & Attendance.

and each module of these has sub-modules.

So I have two questions here.

1. Should I create one API for the whole HR system with multiple areas
   or one API for each module of these or one API for each sub-module?
2. Should I create another API for external usage (I mean one or more tailored for the `HR system` and another one for external systems like `Procurement system` for example) or just aligned with one?
   because when I asked about this some people said:

> API endpoints must be UI agnostic. Tailoring APIs for
> some clients defeats the API ideas and purposes. The best
> design practices tell us to create APIs that express our backend
> store to the outside world regardless who is the outside world.

and others said It's totally fine to have two types of APIs the first for internal use in the solution and the other for interacting with other systems and this's so common when we use client frameworks like `React or angular or blazor assembly` .

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of your system, what you describe seems to indicate multiple APIs would be the better model.

You have described:

- Different deployment locations (DMZ, LAN etc.)
- Different development roadmaps (as per the comment by @John Wu)
- Different security considerations (DMZ, LAN)
- Different consuming systems (including UI) by audience (a recruitment candidate is not going to be using a system that exposes procurement functions)
- And also different authorisation and authentication methods by audience (HR, Hiring managers, Applicants, Staff, procurement officers)

I must admit I find this:

> The best design practices tell us to create APIs that express our backend store to the outside world regardless who is the outside world.

Naïve or dangerous.  It's true to a point but at some level you only want to expose certain parts of your enterprise (backend store) to certain subsets of callers (audience).

> Tailoring APIs for some clients defeats the API ideas and purposes.

Not at all.  As I noted above, a recruitment candidate is not going to be using a system that exposes procurement functions.

For completeness, I do agree that

> API endpoints must be UI agnostic.

Subject to domain constraints noted above.

Comment: I don't know how U conclude all these things! I don't say any thing about these points in my question!
and I don't understand what's the meaning of this: `a recruitment candidate is not going to be using a system that exposes procurement functions.`

Comment: I summarised these points from many, many years of API design.  Perhaps we are at cross purposes - Happy to elaborate where you think I've missed the intention.  You mentioned procurement and recruitment as parts of your system. They are wildly different and so probably should not share an API because they have different audiences and authorisation/authentication, data and function requirements. Perhaps "a system for recruitment candidates is not going to need procurement services" makes it clearer?

Comment: There's misunderstanding here, I agree that I need 2 APIs one for `HR system` and another for `Procurement` My 2 questions are not about this. It's about should I make one API for the whole `HR system` with multiple areas for each subsystem inside like `recruitment` or should I make one `API` for each subsystem. this's the first question. The second one I'm asking about should I create two types of APIs for each system one used internally inside the system and the other to interact with other systems or the internal one enough and should make it more generic and not tailored for this system.

Comment: 1) Lots of APIs for the reasons in my answer!  Different audiences should have different APIs.  How your system is structured is not necessarily relevant (though it might be).  2) Not sure I understand 100% but probably the same answer for the same reasons.  An internal API is a wildly beast from a public one.

Comment: 1-HR system has the same audience , so why should I create multiple APIs for each sub-system in it?
2-I mean that If I have two separate systems one for `HR` the second for `Procurement` and each one has its own API. Should I create another two APIs one for each system to interact together or no need for that.

Comment: Presumably this is a specialised integration interface with no UI or end user functions, locked down to a service account for security etc. In that case yes.

Answer (score 0):

APIs that are combined must be deployed together. APIs that are separate could be deployed independently. So an API is, among other things, a unit of deployment.

Since your internal API may be deployed on an internal network and the external API will be on an external network, they will need to be deployable separately. So they should be separate APIs.

In my experience, compensation systems, especially when they contain commission structures, tend to change fairly frequently. In contrast, a timesheet system pretty much stays the same forever. So it is likely you may need to be able to deploy the compensation more often. In that case, it would be convenient if it were a separate unit of deployment, i.e. a separate API.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer focus on the deployment specifically and my questions are more than that. Could U read the two questions again please. Do You mean by `separate Api` two types of APIs one for the internal solution and the other one for external systems ?